# Cannot print from Windows and printer disapears after reboot

Tags: printing, samba, hp, hplip

I have a home server running Ubuntu 12.04 and have successfully installed my printer (HP Photosmart B109a) on it with hplip. Printed a test page and printed a file from my terminal using:

```
cat somefile.txt | lpr
```

I've setup Samba to share my printer:

```
[printers]
comment = All Printers
browseable = yes
path = /var/spool/samba
printable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = yes
create mask = 0700

[print$]
comment = Printer Drivers
path = /var/lib/samba/printers
browseable = yes
read only = yes
guest ok = yes
```

Still no problem, the printer shows up in as a network printer and I can install it on windows.

But if I try to print via Window's nothing happens. The file does not show in the print queue (neither on Windows or Ubuntu). Even more strange is when I reboot the server, the printer gone in my shared folder. When I restart Samba it returns, but still does not print.

Comment: With same settings my printers work perfectly.  Try to update `samba`.